# Strange holes, shades and rotations in update appear in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, wxwidgets, ubuntu-18.04

I have a code which works perfectly in Ubuntu14 and OpenGL 2.12 (without the "core" in the output of glxinfo) everything looks fine like in Fig. 1. Rotations, shadows and everything look good.

[image]

Then I've compiled and run in 3 machines but with Ubuntu18 OpenGL 4.5 (core) and looks whit holes, strange shadows and rotations are wrong like in Fig 2:

[image]

I have moved the line of the spheres to the bottom and seems to correct the cylinders coming into the sphere but that does not solve the problem, instead of show you the 3D geometrics according to rotations shows in sequence of how you put the objects, so the last object you put in the scene is always on top. I have no clue why is doing this because in the old machines the same code looks ok.

These are the initial parameters which work fine in Ubuntu14...

```
glViewport(subWinWidth * (subWinIndex % colCount), subWinHeight *                    (rowCount - 1 - subWinIndex / colCount), (GLint)subWinWidth, (GLint)subWinHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

...

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);        // Enables Smooth Color Shading

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);        // Enable Depth Buffer
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);           // The Type Of Depth Test To Do

glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glClearColor(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
//Used to display semi-transparent
//glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
//glClear(GL_ALWAYS);

GLfloat ligDif[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
GLfloat ligSpe[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
GLfloat ligPos[] = { -0.8f, 0.7f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
GLfloat ligAmb[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};

GLfloat matAmb[] = {0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f};
GLfloat matDif[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
GLfloat matSpe[] = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f};
GLfloat matEmi[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
GLfloat matShi[] = {100.0f};

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ligAmb);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, ligDif);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, ligSpe);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, ligPos);

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, matAmb);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, matDif);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, matSpe);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, matEmi);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, matShi);

...

 glPushMatrix();
 glTranslatef(atom->pos.x, atom->pos.y, atom->pos.z);
...
 sphere = gluNewQuadric();
 gluSphere(sphere, dispRadius, Slices, Stacks);

...

 gluCylinder(pObjQuadric, radius, radius, distance, slices, stacks);
 gluDeleteQuadric(pObjQuadric);

...
```

I didn't have any error message in the graphic part at least. I got warning messages but with wxWidget lib.

Comment: You are using OpenGL immediate mode with OpenGL 3.0, which is not supported. Most likely your application is using a compatibility profile, which may have some flaws in its immediate mode implementation. Either force it to require a 2.0 profile if possible, or update your code to use modern OpenGL.

Comment: glDepthFunc(GL_NEVER) means no fragment passes the depth test. I'm surprised you got anything drawn on the screen at all. If you want help you should reduce your code to a [mcve] first, as the code you have not shared is probably part of the answer.

Comment: The weird stripes along the cilinders might be explained by your use of `slices` (different from `Slices` a few lines above it). But we will never know...

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. Sergio Monteleone I had the wrong version of OpneGL the actual version is 4.5.

Comment: Botje I had wrong the glDepthFunc(GL_NEVER), the actual is glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL). I think I tried all of them. The slices and stacks are defined in different voids and getting the values in this way:  slices = GetUIProps()->openGLProps.movingObjectSlices;
        stacks = GetUIProps()->openGLProps.movingObjectStacks;

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the old computers that I've tested have Nvidia Drivers, and the new computers had integrated intel GPU, which means those use the Mesa Drivers. The problem is when you enable glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); Nvidia drivers put by default the GL_DEPTH_BITS = 24 while Mesa Drivers put GL_DEPTH_BITS = 0. That makes glDepthFunc(); useless and draw the objects according to the sequence to put them in the scene regardless of the z-coordinate (distance to your camera or view) that brings z-fighting problems (shades), etc. So, the solution is when you create the window with GLUT, for example, use the command:

glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH);

or if you are using wxWidgets:

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_g_l_canvas.html#a56d0a2a022c0c34b7efa1114da151177

with attrib WX_GL_DEPTH_SIZE = 24 or wherever.

Thanks, everyone for your comments.